# App crashes upon clicking button in Fragment to show TimePickerDialog

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-timepicker

I'm trying to display a TimePickerDialog in a Fragment. When the button is clicked, the TimePickerDialog does not appear and the app crashes. There is a class cast issue stated in the logcat.

AlarmFragment class:

```
public class AlarmFragment extends Fragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View alarmView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alarm, container, false);

        Button button = (Button) alarmView.findViewById(R.id.end_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
                timePicker.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "time picker");
            }
        });

        return alarmView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        TextView textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.time_textView);
        textView.setText("Hour: " + hourOfDay + " Minute: " + minute);
    }

}
```

TimePickerFragment class:

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(), hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
        return timePickerDialog;
    }
}
```

Error Message in logcat:

```
2019-07-22 18:07:49.104 4872-4872/mapp.com.sg.thesleepingsheep E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: mapp.com.sg.thesleepingsheep, PID: 4872
    java.lang.ClassCastException: mapp.com.sg.thesleepingsheep.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.TimePickerDialog$OnTimeSetListener
        at mapp.com.sg.thesleepingsheep.TimePickerFragment.onCreateDialog(TimePickerFragment.java:21)
        at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onGetLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:330)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performGetLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1308)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: You just need to use only _getSupportFragmentManager()_ or _getChildFragmentManager()_ if it is with nested fragment

Answer (score 0):

Your `MainActivity` class must implement `TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener`in order to be  able to use : `(TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity()`

Answer (score 0):

Your error is implementing the Listener in your Fragment (`class AlarmFragment ... implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener`) but passing your Activity as the listener to the Dialog (`new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), ...);`. Either implement the listener in your Activity or pass your Fragment as the listener.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement `TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener` in your `TimePickerFragment`

Answer (score 0):

Use getChildFragmentManager() if it is nested fragment

Answer (score 0):

just change the constructor of your `TimePickerFragment` class to accept context also.

```
private Context mContext;

public TimePickerFragment(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context
}
```

And use that `mContext` everywhere in `TimePickerFragment` class wherever you need. Like in `onCreateDialog` method,

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(mContext, mContext, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(mContext));
    return timePickerDialog;
}
```

And initialise your time picker in fragment like this,

```
DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment(getActivity());
```

Comment: I'm getting this error now. I think `mContext` was null. What can I do about it?

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ContentResolver android.content.Context.getContentResolver()' on a null object reference`